# Printing Unicode code point to console using int intead of \uNNNN

Tags: c#, unicode

apologies if this is silly. How do I print a Unicode character, say \u20ac using an integer? So, instead of `Console.WriteLine("\u20ac");`, I would like to pass the integer 8364.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the number to `char` which represents a UTF-16 code point:

```
public static void PrintChar(int codePoint)
{
    Console.WriteLine((char) codePoint);
}

PrintChar(8364);
```

Comment: However, just looked at the definition of char and it goes up to ffff, how do you do the same for astral planes?

Comment: @Dervin: For characters not in the BMP, you need to use surrogate pairs.

Comment: right, that's what I'm doing (from scratch, I'm not using any functions from .net). That's why, suppose I do get the right integer, &#66374, how do I write that to to stdout (doesn't matter that the glyph is not available)?