# Printing Astral Plane Unicode code point to console using int

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-16, astral-plane

Please see here for a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424067/printing-unicode-code-point-to-console-using-int-intead-of-unnnn).

However, `char` goes to `0xffff` (or `65535`). I need to write `0xd800df46` (or `66374`), Gothic letter Faihu, so casting that `int` to `char` will not work. I do the conversion ok, that is, I get the correct integer, meaning I calculate the surrogate pairs ok, but I don't know how to "render" it, convert it to a character to be output as a glyph.

Please notice that I cannot use \Unnnn for ... well, theoretical reasons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you need to convert a single integer into a *surrogate pair* which you'd represent as a string:

```
string x = char.ConvertFromUtf32(66374);
```

For more operations than that, you can use my `Utf32String` class in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), as well as various other methods in `System.Char`.